# AuditorAware is not working for Many-Many relationship

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, audit

I use Spring data AuditorAware feature to audit CreatedBy,LastModifiedBy,CreatedDate and LastModifiedDate. It perfectly works for all the entities even when an entity is in one-many relationship. But It doesn't work for many-many relation ship.

For Ex, 
I have entities `user` and `user_group` with many-many relationship. So it has another table `user_group_association` with `user_id` and `user_group_id`

Whenever there is an create or update in usergroup then audit columns get updated in `usergroup` table. But within the same transaction if any create/update to `user_group_association` there is no changes for these columns.

As I define many-many relation ship as below, I wouldn't have an entity class for `user_group_association`

```
// bi-directional many-to-many association to Users through
// user_group_association
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
@JoinTable(name = "user_group_association", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_group_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
private Set<User> users;
```

How can I force Spring Data to make entires in `user_group_association` table as well ?

Comment: Im facing the same problem. Did you get any solution?

Comment: Created a entity for UserGroupAssociation to solve this

Comment: already have entity for the join table but still does not work. Do you have sample code for reference? TIA